# Как повесить датапикер в бутстрапе ?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Как повесить датапикер в бутстрапе ? - в изначальном я ненашел датапикера, понял что только люди делают самопальные модули, излазил гугл, прошу подсказать как обойтись малой кровью, что бы на ипут повесить датапикер ?

Answer (score 3):

Малой кровью.

[Datepicker for Bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

> Add datepicker picker to field or to any other element.
>
> - can be used as a component
> - formats: dd, d, mm, m, yyyy, yy
> - separators: -, /, .

Answer (score 0):

Самый элементарный - `<input type="date"`